# How can I improve my typescript for this map of functions?

Tags: typescript

I am learning more about typescript and recently wrote this code:

```
type Operator = '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' | undefined;

const actions: { [operator: string]: Function } = {
    '+': (a: number, b: number) => a + b,
    '-': (a: number, b: number) => a - b,
    '*': (a: number, b: number) => a * b,
    '/': (a: number, b: number) => a % b === 0
        ? a / b
        : null,
    undefined: (a: number) => a,
};
```

I feel like currently its fairly poorly typed and could be more neat by somehow extracting out the idea of a functions which take one or two numbers to a separate type?

Do you have any suggestions on how I can improve on my code?

Comment: This would be a good question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define a function type:

```
type Operation = (a: number, b: number) => number;
```

Then:

```
const actions: { [operator: string]: Operation } = {
    ...
}
```